# How to combine variables into new variable?

Tags: ansible

I have Ansible task defined in custom role:

```
- name: Connect to db
  script: "shell.sh --url={{ db_conn }}"
```

Variable **db_conn** defined in playbook:

```
 vars : 
  db_host: "localhost"
  db_port: 5432
  db_conn: "http://{{ db_host }}:{{ db_port }}"
```

Ansible terminates with error:

> A variable inserted a new parameter into the module args. Be sure to quote variables if they contain equal signs (for example: "{{var}}").

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this using what you have shown. Is that exactly how you have your playbook and role set up? What version of Ansible are you using?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR likewise and had same question :)

Comment: 1.9.3  on mac os ,  node -  CentOS 7

Comment: for the fun of it, try a simpler concatenation: `"{{ db_host }}_{{ db_port }}"`. The theory is that the colons are messing it up.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem  with [variable precedence](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). I'm guessing that you defined the `db_conn` variable in your role's `vars/main.yaml` file? 
If so, then `db_conn` is considered a *role variable*, and has higher precedence than *playbook vars* (will not be overwritten by *playbook vars*).

When creating roles with variables you want to have overwritten, make sure they are defined as [defaults](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#role-default-variables) to ensure that they not only get overwritten, but to clearly communicate to others that you intend them to be overwritten.

Just in case the docs are not enough for you, [here is the source code which defines variable precedence from github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/vars/__init__.py#L175).